# CSS: Parent div ignores child width

Tags: css, flexbox, aspect-ratio

I'm using an image to keep a div in a 1:1 aspect ratio. The div is supposed to fill the available height inside a flex-container. The flex-container's width should fit its content.

The square-div has the correct dimensions, but its parent div ignores its width.

Setting an absolute value for the image's width made the parent use the correct width, but I need the image to resize dynamically so that's unfortunately not an option. Can anyone help?

```css
.parent {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 16px;
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
  z-index: 1;
}

.header,
.footer {
  height: 48px;
  width: 100%;
}

.square {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
}

.square>img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="square">
    <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" width="100" height="100" />
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Other things I tried:
Setting the parent div to `width: auto` did not work.
Setting the parent div to `display: inline-flex` did not work.
Setting the parent div to `display: table` did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Feels like you just want a stack with size based on content which you can do with a grid pretty easily.

You had with/height of the image both at 100 which I removed - I used your paste image as the "image" here just for convenience - don't let that distract you. I also changed some colors and put a border on the image just to show what is where for this example. (really much of that below the `.parent {` css is just for this purpose) except the image

I used some CSS just to center the element content.

```
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
```

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
height: 100vh;
  background-color: #00000040;
  border-radius: 0.75em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-columns: 100vw;
  padding: 1em;
}

.header,
.square,
.footer {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.header {
  background-color: #00ff0020;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #0000ff20;
}

.square {
  background-color: #ff000020;
  overflow:auto;
 }

.square>img {
  border: solid 1px magenta;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="header">test header</div>
  <div class="square">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7pL9.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="footer">footer<div>MORE test text</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I re-read the question and did a slight update to the CSS;  Image should respond to the height set in the grid height `10em` currently for the middle block.  I might be missing some understanding of the requirement but this is just a super fast post

Comment: Thanks for the reply! CSS grid seems to be too rigid for my case. The height of the footer and header depend on their content, while the "square" element should fill the remaining height inside the flex-box, whose height is based on the screen size.

Comment: "The height of the footer and header depend on their content, ": YES this does that.  "the "square" element should fill the remaining height": YES just set the image size to whatever and change `10em` to `auto`  I edited to do that (`1fr auto 1fr` says size to children, take rest, size to children)

Comment: Change the image to be whatever size you need; I randomly picked 200px;  but that could come from the image itself etc.

Comment: I made a jsfiddle with your styling and tweaked it so that my point hopefully becomes clearer. Footer and header are not supposed to fill the parent, only the image is. There seems to be no way to make the middle row automatically stretch over the available height and push other elements to the edges when using grid layout. https://jsfiddle.net/fritzweatshirt/0md94a5b/22/

Comment: Simple change to `auto 1fr auto` perhaps is what you desired. I put a smaller image to show that the middle expands to fill all available space - and scrolls if too large (makes a header/footer always available. Try it full page on the Run to see it change size with the sceen.